# Android soft keyboard theme

Tags: themes, android-softkeyboard

I would like to change the colors (not the layout) of the Android soft keyboard when the user use my application. I can't find a place where to learn this, also the Android documentation doesn't explains this argument.

[image]

This keyboard is too gray!

Comment: I believe you need to develop Android Soft Keyboard and use custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make changes in Soft Keyboard when your app is launch as it's a different application. Android doesn't allow to make changes in other applications using yours.

I suggest developing Android Soft Keyboard with custom themes. There is a sample project for Android Soft Keyboard provided by Google to start with.

Here is the link: [Android Soft Keyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard)